# Kendo Tabstrip select method set

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-tabstrip

I'm using a Kendo TabStrip in my project, and am using an MVC view as the content of a panel, by setting the contentURL for the tab.

This is all working great, although I am having an issue, by trying to set the  select function from my MVC view.

Within my view I have tried:

```
$('#edit').kendoTabStrip().select = function(e){alert('tab has been changed');}
```

And a couple of other ways, however, when I try to set this select method from my view, it doesn't allow me to.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to define the select event in your tabstrip configuration, as explained [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/tabstrip#events-select) and [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/tabstrip/events).

Example:

**Define the select event function**

```
var onSelect = function(e) {
    alert('tab has been changed');
};
```

**Javascript**

```
var tabStrip = $("#edit").kendoTabStrip({
    select: onSelect,
    // etc
}).data("kendoTabStrip");
```

**Kendo MVC**

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
    .Name("edit")
    .Events(events => events.Select("onSelect"))
    //etc
)
```